# Replacing new line char with a string

Tags: bash, github-actions

I've tried several approaches already and none seems to work with Github Actions so far.

I just to read the file containing:

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

And get a string:

```
Line1<br/>Line2<br/>
```

Some stuff works locally on my mac but then not ont he CI.
So far I tried:

```
file_contents=$(cat file/path)
file_content_with_line_breaks=${file_contents//'\n'/<br/>}
```

But this gives me nothing

I had some success with this approach:

```
file_content_with_line_breaks=$(echo "$latest_changes" | tr '\n' '£')
file_content_with_line_breaks=${latest_changes_with_line_breaks//'£'/<br/>}
```

So basically first replacing `\n` char with some other special character and then replacing it with string but on CI it only worked with some basic characters like `@` and I don't wanna do it this way as there might be such characters in the input.

Comment: Does `latest_changes_with_line_breaks=${latest_changes_with_line_breaks//$'\n'/<br\/>}` do what you want?  See [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) (`$'...'`).

Comment: Regarding "**Some stuff works locally on my mac but then not ont he CI.**", are you using the same runner as your local machine i.e. `macos-latest` or similar?

Comment: @Azeem no, GHA runs on ubuntu, which I believe causes some pain while trying to test stuff on my mac

Comment: `printf '%b\n' 'g|.|s|$|<br/>|' ,j ,p Q | ed -s file.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `echo`:

```
file="$(<path/to/file)"

echo "${file//$'\n'/<br/>}<br/>"
```

last `<br/>` appended to the variable is because last line does not contain '\n'.

using `sed`:
`sed -z 's#\n#<br/>#g' path/to/file`

using `awk`:
`awk 'BEGIN{ORS="<br/>"} {print $0}' path/to/file`

using `perl`:
`perl -pe 's#\n#<br/>#' path/to/file`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
perl -pe 's|\n|<br/>|' file
```

Output:

```
Line 1<br/>Line 2<br/>
```